# Add a column value from another table as default constant

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have hasOne relationship. Table words hasOne category and table categories belongsTo word. Categories has a foreign key of 'word_id'. How do I do so that value for word_id in categories is taken from id column in table words as default??

Comment: If your ```words``` table and ```categories``` table are in one to one relationship and  what is your question? can you give more explanation?

Comment: The only way that I know how to do that is to set it up in your migration. Setup a foreign key column in there and use ->default(1) or whatever default value you need (referencing the values of the other table).

Comment: Plrease provide detailed example of those tables

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but assuming you have correctly setup your models for a [One To One relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one), Laravel can automatically fill the `word_id` column for you when you create a new category from an existing word.

Example:

```
$word->category()->create([
    'some_key' => 'Some value', // Don't need to pass word_id, Laravel will fill it automatically
]);
```